How to Extract Clusters with Multiple Rows Using Bash Commands?
I'm trying to extract clusters from a text file using Bash commands. Each cluster is delineated by a line starting with >Cluster. I want to extract only those clusters with more than one data row within them. Here's a simplified example of my input file:
>Cluster 199
0       2599aa, >CAD5117741.1... *
>Cluster 200
0       2579aa, >CAD5112262.1... *
>Cluster 201
0       2578aa, >CAD5116287.1... *
>Cluster 202
0       2578aa, >CAD5122864.1... *
1       1867aa, >CAD5122865.1... at 100.00%
2       2369aa, >CAD5122866.1... at 100.00%
>Cluster 203
0       2573aa, >CAD5110750.1... *
>Cluster 204
0       2571aa, >CAD5116249.1... *
>Cluster 205
0       2558aa, >CAD5122682.1... *
>Cluster 206
0       2553aa, >CAD5126525.1... *
>Cluster 207
0       2551aa, >CAD5115834.1... *

In this example, I want to extract only Cluster 202 because it has more than one row of data within it. The desired output would be:
>Cluster 202
0       2578aa, >CAD5122864.1... *
1       1867aa, >CAD5122865.1... at 100.00%
2       2369aa, >CAD5122866.1... at 100.00%

I'm currently using awk to process the file but struggling to figure out how to extract these clusters properly. Can someone guide me in accomplishing this task efficiently using Bash commands?
I attempted to use the following awk command:
awk '/^>Cluster/ {cluster=$0; count=0; next} {count++} count > 1 {print cluster; print} count == 0 {print cluster}'

When applied to the provided data, it produced the following output:
>Cluster 202 2 2369aa, >CAD5122866.1... at 100.00%

This output is incomplete, as it should include all lines within Cluster 202.

consider manually stepping through your script for each line of input; what happens when count == 1? count == 0 never occurs

fwiw, when I run your script against the sample data I get a different set of output ... you show a single line of output while on my system I get 4 lines of output:  >Cluster 202 / 1       1867aa, >CAD5122865.1... at 100.00% / >Cluster 202 / 2       2369aa, >CAD5122866.1... at 100.00%; at this point I'm assuming you've cut-n-pasted a mismatched set of code and (wrong) output ... ?

Here is a simple working script (just tested and without awk):
#!/bin/bash

function process_cluster {
    
    input_file=$1
    current_cluster=""
    data_rows=0

    while read -r line; do
        if [[ $line == ">Cluster "* ]]; then
            if [[ $data_rows -gt 1 ]]; then
                echo -e "$current_cluster" 
            fi
            
            current_cluster="$line"  
            data_rows=0
        else
            ((data_rows++))
            current_cluster="$current_cluster\n$line" 
        fi
    done < $input_file

    if [[ $data_rows -gt 1 ]]; then
        echo -e "$current_cluster"
    fi

}

process_cluster clusters.txt > output.txt

Remember to save your input data into a file named clusters.txt or change it into the above script.

I edit it with your request...

Regarding "and without awk" - avoiding awk when you need to manipulate text from a shell is like avoiding the washing machine when it's laundry day. In addition to being more code than an awk script, this will run orders of magnitude slower than an awk script and is less portable than an awk script with no benefits over using an awk script. Please read why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

Using any awk in 1 pass of reading the input and only storing 1 ^>-separated record at a time in memory:
awk '
    /^>/ { prt(); rec=$0; next }
    { rec = rec ORS $0 }
    END { prt() }
    function prt() { if (gsub(ORS,"&",rec)>1) print rec }
' file
>Cluster 202
0       2578aa, >CAD5122864.1... *
1       1867aa, >CAD5122865.1... at 100.00%
2       2369aa, >CAD5122866.1... at 100.00%


With your shown samples Only, please try following in GNU awk.
awk -v RS='(^|\n)>' 'RT && num=split($0,arr,ORS)>2' Input_file


Probably you don't need to do num= here

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
>Cluster 199
0       2599aa, >CAD5117741.1... *
>Cluster 200
0       2579aa, >CAD5112262.1... *
>Cluster 201
0       2578aa, >CAD5116287.1... *
>Cluster 202
0       2578aa, >CAD5122864.1... *
1       1867aa, >CAD5122865.1... at 100.00%
2       2369aa, >CAD5122866.1... at 100.00%
>Cluster 203
0       2573aa, >CAD5110750.1... *
>Cluster 204
0       2571aa, >CAD5116249.1... *
>Cluster 205
0       2558aa, >CAD5122682.1... *
>Cluster 206
0       2553aa, >CAD5126525.1... *
>Cluster 207
0       2551aa, >CAD5115834.1... *

then
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">Cluster";ORS="";FS="\n"}NF>3{print RS $0}' file.txt

gives output
>Cluster 202
0       2578aa, >CAD5122864.1... *
1       1867aa, >CAD5122865.1... at 100.00%
2       2369aa, >CAD5122866.1... at 100.00%

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK to use >Cluster as row separator, use empty string as output row separator and use newline as field separator. Then for rows (cluster block) with more than 3 fields I print that block, I need to prefix it with row separator as it is not part of row. It is >3 because single-line block has 3 fields: cluster number, line and empty field after trailing newline.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -n '/^>Cluster/{:a;x;s/\n/&/2p;x;h;d};H;$ba' file

Turn off implicit printing -n.
If a line begins >Cluster, then:

Check to see if the hold space contains 3 or more lines and if so
print them.

Make a copy of the current cluster header in the hold space and
delete that line.


Otherwise, append a copy of the current line to the hold space and perform no further processing.
Unless the current line is the last line, then proceed as if a cluster header has been accepted.
